# Why an exception is thrown out by Mockito?

Tags: exception, mockito

In the following test code, I make a declaration: when the get() method is called with argument 0, then an exception should be thrown out. In my opinion, if the argument is not 0, the exception should not be thrown out. But, the test was passed. That means get(1) has caused an exception was thrown. Is this a bug of Mockito?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {
    @Mock
    private List<Integer> mockedList;

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(mockedList.get(0)).thenThrow(new Exception());
        mockedList.get(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set up your test incorrectly and misinterpreted the outcome of your test.

The problem lies in the line:

```
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

[The signature of "get" method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int)) does not allow checked excetions.
Thus, when you pass a checked exception to `thenThrow`, Mockito rightfully reports it with:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.Exception
```

Thus the exception reported is `MockitoException`, not the `Exception` you passed to `thenThrow`. It is thrown even if you omit a call to `mockedList.get(1);`

To fix, use a `RuntimeException`, preferrably one that can be reported by get.

```
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenThrow(new IndexOutOfBoundsException());
```

Note that you stub a call that is not made afterwards, you need to use a lenient mock with `@Mock(lenient = true)`, otherwise Mockito will report a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException`

Comment: I get it. Thanks for your careful answer.

Comment: @Parmenides If that solved the problem, please consider accepting the answer